# WordPress: Develop multiple posts with different data

Tags: posts, plugin-development, pages

I have a landing page of multiple books as a post, I want to display each book in separated post, in each post has a book name,download link,image and size. All books posts has same design with different data. 
I was thinking to create each book in child theme but it's too many books and will be many files and many wordpress pages .
What is the correct idea to develop that ?

Comment: why you wanna do this? Just create a single post template or a cpt to hold the books

Comment: It's not the matter of too many books, if you want to deal the things in WordPress' way, you have to go with a custom post type (CPT) and that's it. If you want to go with custom tables go with `$wpdb` class and do it. But if you want something like a bulk-uploader, you can have some glimpse from [this blog](http://tuts.nanodesignsbd.com/csv-bengali-import-using-php-mysql/) (in Bengali). You can go with the code-snippets for WordPress.